# CORS policy blocked when using google cloudrun

Tags: flask, cors, google-cloud-run

I have a web app that sends HTTP requests to an API (using Flask) that I hosted on google cloud run (hosted separately). When hosting the API and web app locally, it was working and sending requests as expected but after hosting the service to cloud run, i encountered this CORS error:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at (API address) from the origin (web app address) has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource"

I am confused about whether this is caused by the code or due to how i set up my cloud run environment. I have included CORS on my flask api and even send back a header.

.JS file

```
var url = host + "/getOpenedAccounts/" + currentUser.uid;
    fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
```

flask file

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import pymysql

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route("/getCustomerDetails/<customerID>", methods = ['GET'])
def returnCustomerDetails(customerID):
      #Connecting to the database
      cnx = pymysql.connect(#Connection to my database)
      cursor = cnx.cursor()
      #Fetch entry in database using customerID
      query1 = ("select * from customer Where customerID = '" + customerID +"';")
      cursor.execute(query1)
      data = cursor.fetchone()
      if data is not None:
            newC = createCustomer(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5],   data[6])
            resp = flask.Response(newC.toJson())
            resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
            return resp
      return"200 OK: Customer not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

`from flask_cors import CORS,cross_origin`

And also add the following line below your app.route.

`@cross_origin(origin='*')`